# Testing iOS PhoneGap Application in Windows

Tags: ios, cordova, kendo-ui

Is there an established method for developing and testing an iOS PhoneGap application on Windows? We're talking about straight HTML/Javascript/CSS here. My first thought was to test with Safari with windows at various sizes (ie. 320x480 for 3GS). However, I don't know how accurate that is with regards to how the UI will respond and how images will display (especially relating to retina displays). Any ideas?

Comment: If you're concerned with accuracy, you *must* test on your *target platform*, i.e. on an iOS device. Anything else -- even the iPhone/iPad simulator in the iOS SDK -- is just an educated guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the Ripple Mobile Enviroment Emulator for Chrome

[Ripple](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc)

Comment: I used Ripple on windows, I will not suggest this tools because some time it will not give you actual problem, which occur on device. I suggest you to use device randomly.